# Inverse a simple equation

Tags: logarithms, inverse

Consider equation
$y = x\cdot 2^x$

Can you write $x$ based on $y$ ?
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Not using standard functions.

Comment: Write it as $y\ln(2)=(x\ln(2))\cdot e^{x\ln(2)}$ and see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: this is not one-by-one function ! so it can't be invertible !

Answer (score 1):

The solution requires the Lambert W function:

$$ x = \dfrac{W(y \ln(2))}{\ln(2)} $$